# save seleted item from data grid view to textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I've got 3 forms `form1`, `form2`, `form3`.form1 will load/run first. When i press a button in `form1` it will open a new `form2` which has a textbox. When I click the textbox it will open `form3` which has a datagridview which contains multiple rows.

So I've used a context menu strip in `form3` and I've named the item as select, say if I select the datagridview row and select contextmenustrip item select (say datagridview has two columns name and pin code) the pin code must be outputted in textbox present in `form2`. I tried but nothing happened.

**form1 buttonclick event**:

```
    private void AddBusMasterBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form2 Obj = new Form2();
        Obj.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }
```

`form2` has a textbox which when I click will open a new form which has a datagrid view and context menu strip with item called select and if I select strip with item select it must place the selected row item in the textbox of the `form2`

```
    private void FromStopIDtextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 obj = new Form3();
        obj.ShowDialog();
    }
```

this is the select context menu strip item

```
    private void selectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
        string StopId_var = dataGridView1[0, Row].Value.ToString();
        form2 obj = new form2();
        obj.textbox.text = StopId_var;

        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Form3 obj = new Form3(ref textBox);
obj.ShowDialog();
```

You need to create a second constructor of `Form3`, which get the textbox from Form2, as reference.

```
 Textbox textbox;
    public Form3(ref TextBox _textbox)
    {
       InitializeComponents();
      textbox = _textbox;
    }
```

Now, when the menuitem is clicked, you have to assign the value of the current clicked row col value to the textbox text;

```
 private void selectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        int Row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
        string StopId_var = dataGridView1[0, Row].Value.ToString();
        textbox.Text = StopId_var;
        this.Close();
  }
```